# How do I get onActivityResult() to execute?

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I'm trying to implement speech recognition and storing the results from the person's response as part of a game I am creating, however for some reason `onActivityResult()` never gets executed. I've debugged into the issue and can't seem to find a reason as to why this is happening. I created and implemented my custom `ActionResolver` interface to allow me to use android's libraries alongside LibGDX to implement this feature.

Below is my code:

```
    public class ActionResolverAndroid extends Activity implements ActionResolver {

    Handler handler;

    private Intent speechIntent;
    private boolean isCorrectResponse = false;

    static final int check = 1;

    private ArrayList<String> phrases = new ArrayList<String>();

    public ActionResolverAndroid() {
        handler = new Handler();

        phrases.add("hello");
        phrases.add("apartments");
        phrases.add("creativity");
        phrases.add("mountains");
        phrases.add("fruits");
        phrases.add("education");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Gdx.app.log("Are we here yet?", "are we here?");


        ArrayList<String> responses = data.getStringArrayListExtra((RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS));
        for (int i = 0; i < responses.size(); i++) {
            responses.get(i).toLowerCase();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < phrases.size(); i++) {
            if (phrases.get(i).equals(responses.get(0))) {
                System.out.println("Correct word! 1 point son!");
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Correct!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isCorrectResponse(true);
            } else if (!isCorrectResponse && i == phrases.size() - 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println("Wrong word!");

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void implementVoiceRecognizer() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                speechIntent = new Intent(
                        RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

                speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                        RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                speechIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
                        "Say the phrase!");

                startActivityForResult(speechIntent, check);



            }
    });

    }

    @Override
    public void isCorrectResponse(boolean b) {
                isCorrectResponse = b;

    }

    public boolean isCorrectResponse() {
        return isCorrectResponse;
    }

    // public void setIsCorrectResponse(boolean b){
    // isCorrectResponse = b;
    // }

    public Intent getSpeechIntent() {
        return speechIntent;
    }

}
```

This is the error printed to the LogCat when I run the game on my tablet:

```
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248): Process: com.mygdx.Dextero.android, PID: 15248
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3457)
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248):    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3418)
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248):    at com.mygdx.Dextero.android.ActionResolverAndroid$1.run(ActionResolverAndroid.java:74)
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
10-22 15:39:02.091: E/AndroidRuntime(15248):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 15:39:02.826: V/SurfaceView(15248): com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.surfaceview.GLSurfaceView20{41c53d30 VFE..... .F....I. 0,0-1280,736} got resized: w=1280 h=736, cur w=-1 h=-1
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace this:

```
((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(speechIntent, check);
```

with just this:

```
startActivityForResult(speechIntent, check);
```

You are invoking the Result call from another Activity and the current one does not receive it.

Also, there is no need to pass a Context object in the constructor of an Activity, as each Activity is a Context itself :-)

Comment: Hi Kelevandos, I am getting a NullPointerException when I replaced that line with your solution. I don't understand why exactly that's happening.

Comment: And what is null exactly?

Comment: `startActivityForResult(speechIntent, check);`

Comment: Could you update the question with a stacktrace of the NullPointer?